# How attach the SQL script by SQLPlus to the bash loop?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

I want to clear the table from all data (**Table_with_DB** (it is in program sqldeveloper)) through **sqlplus** and based on filenames in the path (**path/to/files**) using SQLPlus completes the table (Table_with_DB) the filenames that are in the path.

I create 2 separate SQL files
(**clear.sql** ; **register.sql**)

and 1 with bash (**bashloop.sh**)

**clear.sql**

```sql
BEGIN 
 package.clear('Table_with_DB'); 
END;
```

**register.sql**

```sql
BEGIN 
 package.register('folderName' , '&1);
END;
```

**bashloop.sh**

```sh
for i in path/to/files;
 do
  sqlplus -s userid/password@ @clear.sql
  sqlplus -s userid/password@ @register.sql
 done
```

I expect the query clear **Table_with_DB** and transfer the filenames from **path/to/files** to **Table_with_DB** using **SQLPlus**

but the actual it not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example sqlplus in loop .

```
#!/bin/bash

username=system
password=passwordsystem
tns_alias=esmd


for i in /opt/oracle/example1/test*/file*.txt;
 do
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus   $username/$password@$tns_alias <<EOF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 2000
    BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('$i');
    END;
/
EOF

done;
```

Example output

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4  /opt/oracle/example1/test2/file2.txt

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Oct 22 13:59:24 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4  /opt/oracle/example1/test3/file3.txt

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Oct 22 13:59:24 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4  /opt/oracle/example1/test4/file4.txt

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~/example1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do then in your bashloop.sh you want to replace **db_name** with **$i** - or ${i} if you have filenames with spaces.

Comment: I change this **db_name**. I want clear all data in table **Table_with_DB** using clear.sql and send new data (which are filenames) from **path/to/files** using register.sql